# Limit bash script to its owner

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, debian

I have different users in `/home`. Each user has a `start.sh` script and a `start.conf` for configuration. Also `start.sh` in linked to `/bin/nameoftheuser` to make typing easier *(This adds more complexity to the question)*.

I want to limit the script to the user that works with it. What I currently do is this:

```
cd
if [ -f start.conf ]; then
    . start.conf
else
    echo "start.conf not found"
    exit 2
fi

if [ $(whoami) != $SCRIPTUSER ]; then
    echo "You are logged in with $(whoami). Only $SCRIPTUSER is allowed to use this script"
    exit 2
fi
```

`$SCRIPTUSER` is defined in `start.conf`. But when I'm logged in with the wrong user and I want to use `start.sh`, the wrong configuration file gets included so the second part of the code doesn't catch the mistake.

**In the end, each user should limit their `start.sh` script excluselive to them and others should not be able to call it by accident**

---

One idea could be comparing the owner of `$0` to the current user. But when there is a symbolic link in `/bin/nameoftheuser`, the symbolic link is owned by **root**.

Including the configuration file and reading what user is allowed to use it and compare `$(whoami)` to it, does also not satisfy. This is because a different user could call it and include their own `start.conf`

Comment: This all seems petty convoluted. Which problem is this design supposed to solve?

Comment: `sudo chmod 700 /home/*`

Comment: If `start.conf` were `chmod 600` the mistake you describe should be impossible. You might want to add a check for read access to this file. ... Or, what Cyrus just said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you simply use file permissions?

```
chmod 700 script.sh
```

That's it.

Comment: Because people tend to use `chmod +x ...` on every script and therefore mistakes easily happen

Comment: You should not care about such people. A big operating system vendor from Redmond did so. You see where it ended ... :)

Comment: You're right. I think I should not make it entirely idiot proof. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Give proper documentation, or even automate the installation process as possible. That should work. If still someone messes up the permissions, then don't care about that.

Answer (score 1):

This will find the owner of the symbolic link

```
owner=$(stat --format '%U' $(readlink -f /bin/nameoftheuser))
```